# Why does Clang interprets an explicit cast as an implicit cast ?

Tags: c++, c, casting, clang

I have recently been working with `Clang`, and this little curiosity always occurs when an explicit cast is parsed.

To explicit my point, here is some basic code :

```
int main(){
    int my_int; 
    float my_float; 

    my_int = (int) my_float; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Of course you would expect `my_int = (int) my_float;` to be parsed as a [CStyleCastExpr](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CStyleCastExpr.html), with a [CastKind](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/namespaceclang.html#aa8bdb68daa57cbb2096f354001e2df8c) of `CK_FloatingToIntegral`, but it is not the case, and, in fact, the nature of the cast is stored inside an [ImplicitCastExpr](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ImplicitCastExpr.html) while the `CStyleCastExpr` holds a `NoOp` nature.

Here is the matching AST-dump for this code :

```
|-DeclStmt 0x2eb3528 <line:3:1, col:11>
| `-VarDecl 0x2eb34d0 <col:1, col:5> my_int 'int'
|-DeclStmt 0x2eb35a8 <line:4:1, col:15>
| `-VarDecl 0x2eb3550 <col:1, col:7> my_float 'float'
|-BinaryOperator 0x2eb3678 <line:5:1, col:16> 'int' lvalue '='
| |-DeclRefExpr 0x2eb35c0 <col:1> 'int' lvalue Var 0x2eb34d0 'my_int' 'int'
| `-CStyleCastExpr 0x2eb3650 <col:10, col:16> 'int' <NoOp>
|   `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x2eb3638 <col:16> 'int' <FloatingToIntegral>
|     `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x2eb3620 <col:16> 'float' <LValueToRValue>
|       `-DeclRefExpr 0x2eb35e8 <col:16> 'float' lvalue Var 0x2eb3550 'my_float' 'float'
`-ReturnStmt 0x2eb36c0 <line:6:1, col:8>
  `-IntegerLiteral 0x2eb36a0 <col:8> 'int' 0
```

It seems a little bit confusing since an `ImplicitCastExpr` should, for me, only be recognized when some unexpected cast occurs (See code below).

```
int main(){
    int my_int;
    float my_float; 

    // implicit cast from float to int
    my_int = my_float;
    return 0; 
}
```

Would you have some explanation for this ?

Comment: how about `static_cast<int>(my_float)` ?

Comment: I don't have any troubles with my casts, they do fine. But for my personal knowledge I'm curious about the answer. Is it some Clang misleading conception ?

Comment: My comment is whether the `(int)my_float` is no an implicit cast for the language, while explicit would be more along the lines of `static_cast<..>()`, `const_cast<...>()` etc. I'm not a standards expert.

Comment: You experience this with both `C` and `C++`?

Comment: No, this is only valid for C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a side effect coming from clang's implementation :

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/17369

The source code file generating the cast nodes is :

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Sema/SemaCast.cpp